# How to run maven project using an ant script?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have created the sample maven project and I am able to build maven project successfully using with maven plugin (mvn clean, mvn install ...) but I want to run the sample maven project using an ant script (ant clean, ant) without using maven goals.

**Is this possible to run maven project using with ant script?**

Comment: You can run the generated app via exec-maven-plugin (Maven way).

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise, Actually I can do everything through the maven way and need to do the something through the ant script with help of dependencies files and pom.xml of sample project.

Answer (score 2):

You can pick and choose the following three ways

1. Ant exec task
2. Ant java task
3. [Maven ant task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html)

Comment: Thanks Lan, I will try any one of this way and get back to you.