# Running a maven task from an ant build file

Tags: maven, ant

I have directory called 'maventest' which contains a 'pom.xml' file. The exact location is:
`C:\CIA-LDM-Branches-rc\LDMRC160\tools\maventest\pom.xml`
Now I want to write an ant build file which will change into above directory and run the mvn command:
`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`

Can any one please provide me the code for this.

Comment: There is a number of valid answers provided here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581156/how-to-call-for-a-maven-goal-within-an-ant-script

Comment: See also: https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run maven project using an ant script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411659/how-to-run-maven-project-using-an-ant-script)